# run vaadin application on pc

Tags: java, vaadin

I have developed a vaadin application for a friend of me. Now I want to "install" this application on his pc so that when he clicks on an icon (like when you open, let's say spotify) the application starts and he can start using it... What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application would be an runnable jar (using JSmooth or whatever you want). You would need to use an `embeddable` web server like Jetty. Here is a [tutorial on setting up Vaadin with Weld and embedded Jetty](http://www.smartjava.org/content/embedded-jetty-vaadin-and-weld). Here is an [example Vaadin application](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/releases/6.6.4/src/com/vaadin/launcher/) that shows you how to set up the launcher to automatically start your application.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You could also use something like [portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and package that into your executive, as [Sami did in this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/654726).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) to create an installer for the application.

Comment: And who starts the application server? I thinks the vaadin application needs a server ...